# Zariski density for certain subsemigroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Suppose that we have a Zariski-dense subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\GL(d,\mathbb{R})$. Let $\delta$ be the abscissa of convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{x \in \Gamma} e^{-s \log\|x\|}
$$
and suppose that this series diverges at $s = \delta$. If we have a subsemigroup $N$ of $\Gamma$ such that
$$
\sum_{x \in N} e^{-\delta \log\|x\|} = \infty
$$
can we conclude that $N$ is Zariski dense in $\GL(d,\mathbb{R})$? (Edit: it has been pointed out in the comments that $N$ being Zariski dense is equivalent to the subgroup generated by $N$ being Zariski dense).

Intuitively this feels like it should be true - but I can't see a way in to prove it! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The inverse of an element is in its Zariski closure so this is equivalent to whether the group generated by N is Zariski dense.

Comment: In more detail, my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/246974/zariski-density-reference-request shows the Zariski closure of a subsemigroup is a group over an algebraically closed field using Ax-Grothendieck.  But this is also valid over R by Białynicki-Birula, A., Rosenlicht, M.: Injective Morphisms of Real Algebraic Varieties.  Maybe there is a more direct argument to deduce or from the complex case

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I'll add a reference to this in the question.

Comment: Actually reading the comments to my answer a Zariski closed submonoid M of GL_n is a subgroup just because any closed subspace is Noetherian and a direct algebraic argument

Comment: Eventually if $\Lambda$ is the subgroup generated by $N$, then $\sum_{x\in\Lambda}e^{-\delta\|x\|}=\infty$. Hence, it is no restriction to assume that $N$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Where did the question occur?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6817 may be useful?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @YCor, it came up whilst reading about counting problems related to certain representations into GL(d,R). @rpotrie, thanks for the reference - do we know that we can associate a `nice action' to a subgroup of GL(d,R) so that the norm function behaves like displacement?

Comment: I don't know, but if your group is not discrete then the series never converges, so perhaps you can make some counterexample that way. I think you should ask that the group $\Gamma$ is discrete, right?

Comment: @rpotrie, you're right, I'd like that $0 < \delta < \infty$.